# Getting uncaught TypeError with a newer version of jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am learning how to build a parent child relationship using webgrid and jquery.
Here is the webgrid

```
         <div id="main" style="padding:25px; background-color:white;">
            @grid.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new {id="gridT", width="700px" },
            columns:grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("order.OrderID","Order ID"),
                    grid.Column(header:"Order Date",format:(item)=> string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",item.order.OrderDate)),
                    grid.Column("order.CustomerName","Customer Name"),
                    grid.Column("order.CustomerAddress","Address"),

                    grid.Column(format:(item)=>{
                        WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.orderDetails);
                        return subGrid.GetHtml(
                            htmlAttributes: new { id="subT" },
                            columns:subGrid.Columns(
                                    subGrid.Column("Product","Product"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Quantity", "Quantity"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Rate", "Rate"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Amount", "Amount")
                                )                    
                            );
                    })
                )
            )
        </div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
        @section Scripts{
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var size = $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").size(); // get total column
                    $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").last().remove(); // remove last column
                    $("#main #gridT > thead > tr").prepend("<th></th>"); // add one column at first for collapsible column
                    $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr").each(function (i, el) {
                        $(this).prepend(
                                $("<td></td>")
                                .addClass("expand")
                                .addClass("hoverEff")
                                .attr('title',"click for show/hide")
                            );

                        //Now get sub table from last column and add this to the next new added row
                        var table = $("table", this).parent().html();
                        //add new row with this subtable
                        $(this).after("<tr><td></td><td style='padding:5px; margin:0px;' colspan='" + (size - 1) + "'>" + table + "</td></tr>");
                        $("table", this).parent().remove();
                        // ADD CLICK EVENT FOR MAKE COLLAPSIBLE
                        $(".hoverEff", this).live("click", function () {
                            $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
                            $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
                        });
                    });

                    //by default make all subgrid in collapse mode
                    $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr td.expand").each(function (i, el) {
                        $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
                        $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
                    });

                });
            </script>
        }
```

This section is not working and running into errors with ".live" (uncaught TypeError $(...)live is not a function). I read online that this has been removed
from newer versions of jquery.

```
        $(".hoverEff", this).live("click", function () {
                            $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
                            $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
                        });
```

I tried changing this to ".on" but still no luck. I am using jquery-1.10.2. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

[`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) were deprecated *years* ago and subsequently removed. The new way is to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: How do I apply the on in this code? on does not work for me. $(".hoverEff", this).on("click", function () {  I am just learning this.

Comment: @user2320476: The documentation for `on` (and `live`, and `delegate`) show clear examples of how to use `on` where you used to use `live` and `delegate`. If you're learning, the first thing to learn is that *documentation is your friend*. :-) `$(document).on("click", ".hoverEff", function() { /*...*/});`

Comment: I tried this and does not work. $(document).on("click", ".hoverEff", function () {
                      $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
                      $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
                });

Comment: @user2320476: Sorry, I misread the original code, which is using the `$(".hoverEff", this)` syntax I wish they'd remove from jQuery (there's talk they may well do that). So: `$(this).on("click", ".hoverEff", function() { /*...*/});` **or something like it**. Again: Documentation is your friend. Read up on `live`, and on `on`, and you'll be able to translate the one to the other.